# How to change lightdm's wallpaper per user?

Tags: ubuntu, lightdm

I changed the display manager from sddm to lightdm.
I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, and slick-greeter as lightdm's greeter.

I remembered that when I was using xfce4 and changed the wallpaper in the xfce4's settings, lightdm's wallpaper was changed when I selected a different user.
I want to set the wallpaper up to be changed per user, as I did then.

However, I don't want to install xfce4 just for that purpose.

Does anyone know how to set up lightdm to change the wallpaper per user without xfce4?

Answer (score 0):

[It seems this is a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287557/cannot-draw-user-backgrounds-on-greeter-mate-20-04). You can use lightdm-gtk-greeter (and lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings to configure it in GUI) for the same behaviour instead, or you can submit a bug report to slick-greeter.

Comment: Thank you for telling. I added that line, but  wallpaper was not changed per user.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287557/cannot-draw-user-backgrounds-on-greeter-mate-20-04 It seems this is a bug. You can use `lightdm-gtk-greeter` (and `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` to configure it in GUI) for the same behaviour instead, or you can submit a bug report to slick-greeter.